# Identify if text in .docx file is collapsible under a certain outline level (Level 1, 2, etc.)

Tags: ms-word, python-docx

I was not able to find anything in the documentation on how to identify if a text is collapsible under a certain outline level.

After a few more digging, I found that it might be possible by looking through the xml. However I was wondering if there was an easier and less complicated way around it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.